# How to load two forge viewers in single web page

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to add two forge viewers in a single web page. I am using "react-forge-viewer" npm package to do that, but for some reason, only one viewer gets loaded and another one stays at "starting viewer..." state. It would be really great if anyone could help me resolve this problem.

I think this might be because of the dependency on class names or ID's.

Also, I want to synch their events in such a way that if I change camera view by dragging on on viewer same thing should reflect on another viewer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily fit multiple Viewers together, just be sure to initialize them separately with distinct container divs:

```
 var viewer1 = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv1'));
 var viewer2 = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv2'));

 Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options1, function() {
  viewer1.start();
  viewer1.load(...);      
 });

 Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options2, function() {
  viewer2.start();
  viewer2.load(...);
 });
```

And you can sync the states of two viewers by subscribing to the `CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT`, but beware pitfalls like endless loops - you can overcome this by implementing critical blocks to ensure only one viewer is exclusively requesting the other viewer to sync at any given time:

```
   viewer1.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, function()
   {
        //critical block to prevent endless chained loop of events 
        viewer2.restoreState(viewer1.getState())
   });   

   viewer2.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, function()
   {
        //critical block to prevent endless chained loop of events 
        viewer1.restoreState(viewer2.getState())
   });
```

See a working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/5gx69s14/).

P.S:`react-forge-viewer` is a third party package `not authored by Autodesk` as is noted in its own README so you might need to contact its author if you have issues with it.

Comment: Restoring state on camera change event for both viewers leads into a loop.

Comment: That's why you will need to implement `critical blocks` to prevent callback loops - see my sample for details.